# Print PDF: Payment Method Configuration could not be found for creditcard

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0

I just updated a heap of modules via the connect manager - most things seems to work so far, however, if I try and create a PDF for an Invoice that was paid by credit card I receive the following error:

```
    Payment Method Configuration could not be found for creditcard

Trace:
#0 /html/live/app/code/community/Payone/Core/Helper/Config.php(176): Payone_Core_Model_Config_Payment->getMethodForQuote('creditcard', Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote))
#1 /html/live/app/code/community/Payone/Core/Model/Payment/Method/Abstract.php(366): Payone_Core_Helper_Config->getConfigPaymentMethodForQuote('creditcard', Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote))
#2 /html/live/app/code/community/Payone/Core/Model/Payment/Method/Abstract.php(84): Payone_Core_Model_Payment_Method_Abstract->getConfigForQuote(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote))
#3 /html/live/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/payment/info/pdf/default.phtml(32): Payone_Core_Model_Payment_Method_Abstract->getTitle()
#4 /html/live/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(412): include('/html/live/app/...')
#5 /html/live/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(274): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#6 /html/live/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(288): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#7 /html/live/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#8 /html/live/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /html/live/app/code/community/Vianetz/AdvancedInvoiceLayout/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php(1384): Mage_Payment_Block_Info->toPdf()
#10 /html/live/app/code/community/Vianetz/AdvancedInvoiceLayout/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php(731): Vianetz_AdvancedInvoiceLayout_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract->_getPaymentMethodText(Object(Billpay_Model_Sales_Order))
#11 /html/live/app/code/community/Vianetz/AdvancedInvoiceLayout/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php(97): Vianetz_AdvancedInvoiceLayout_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract->insertOrderAndPaymentData(Object(Zend_Pdf_Page), Object(Billpay_Model_Sales_Order), true)
#12 /html/live/app/code/community/Vianetz/AdvancedInvoiceLayout/controllers/Adminhtml/InvoiceController.php(51): Vianetz_AdvancedInvoiceLayout_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice->getPdf(Array)
#13 /html/live/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Vianetz_AdvancedInvoiceLayout_Adminhtml_InvoiceController->printAction()
#14 /html/live/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('print')
#15 /html/live/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /html/live/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /html/live/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /html/live/index.php(127): Mage::run('mohrmann', 'website')
#19 {main}
```

The Payment method creditcard seems to exist in the payone module:
[image]

Any help how to try and find the error would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT:

I have gone and disabled the AdvancedInvoiceLayout and the Aitoc modules, however the issue is still there. I truncated the payone_config_payment_method table, and ran the setup wizard again, reconfiguring the creditcard payment.

Here is a screenshot of the table:

[image]

Whenever I want to change an Order in the backend, whenever I want to create an order in the backend ... etc .. I receive the following error trace:

```
    Payment Method Configuration could not be found for creditcard

Trace:
#0 /html/dev/app/code/community/Payone/Core/Helper/Config.php(176): Payone_Core_Model_Config_Payment->getMethodForQuote('creditcard', Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote))
#1 /html/dev/app/code/community/Payone/Core/Model/Payment/Method/Abstract.php(366): Payone_Core_Helper_Config->getConfigPaymentMethodForQuote('creditcard', Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote))
#2 /html/dev/app/code/community/Payone/Core/Model/Payment/Method/Abstract.php(84): Payone_Core_Model_Payment_Method_Abstract->getConfigForQuote(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote))
#3 /html/dev/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/billing/method/form.phtml(38): Payone_Core_Model_Payment_Method_Abstract->getTitle()
#4 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/html/dev/app/d...')
#5 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#6 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#7 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#8 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(577): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('form', true)
#10 /html/dev/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/abstract.phtml(33): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('', true, true)
#11 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/html/dev/app/d...')
#12 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#13 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#18 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreateController.php(414): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#19 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController->loadBlockAction()
#20 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('loadBlock')
#21 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#22 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#23 /html/dev/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#24 /html/dev/index.php(127): Mage::run('mohrmann', 'website')
#25 {main}
```

or

```
    Payment Method Configuration could not be found for creditcard

Trace:
#0 /html/dev/app/code/community/Payone/Core/Helper/Config.php(176): Payone_Core_Model_Config_Payment->getMethodForQuote('creditcard', Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote))
#1 /html/dev/app/code/community/Payone/Core/Model/Payment/Method/Abstract.php(366): Payone_Core_Helper_Config->getConfigPaymentMethodForQuote('creditcard', Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote))
#2 /html/dev/app/code/community/Payone/Core/Model/Payment/Method/Abstract.php(84): Payone_Core_Model_Payment_Method_Abstract->getConfigForQuote(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote))
#3 /html/dev/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/billing/method/form.phtml(38): Payone_Core_Model_Payment_Method_Abstract->getTitle()
#4 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/html/dev/app/d...')
#5 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#6 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#7 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#8 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(577): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('form', true)
#10 /html/dev/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/abstract.phtml(33): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('', true, true)
#11 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/html/dev/app/d...')
#12 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#13 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('billing_method', true)
#18 /html/dev/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/data.phtml(56): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('billing_method')
#19 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/html/dev/app/d...')
#20 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#21 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#22 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#24 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#25 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('data', true)
#26 /html/dev/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/form.phtml(45): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('data')
#27 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/html/dev/app/d...')
#28 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#29 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#30 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#31 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#32 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#33 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('form', true)
#34 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(130): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('form')
#35 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create.php(104): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->getFormHtml()
#36 /html/dev/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/form/container.phtml(37): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create->getFormHtml()
#37 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/html/dev/app/d...')
#38 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#39 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#40 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#41 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#42 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#43 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#44 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#45 /html/dev/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#46 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/html/dev/app/d...')
#47 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#48 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#49 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#50 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#51 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#52 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#53 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/EditController.php(74): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#54 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_EditController->indexAction()
#55 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#56 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#57 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#58 /html/dev/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#59 /html/dev/index.php(127): Mage::run('mohrmann', 'website')
#60 {main}
```

I have contacted the PayOne Developers twice now. 
Once on Tuesday and again today, so far no response!

This is really bad and I need help to try and fix this.

Can anyone help me to try sand pinpoint the errors?

Comment: I see that you have some custom modules installed like `Payone_Core` and  `Vianetz_AdvancedInvoiceLayout`. I think you should call the developers for this.

Comment: I disabled the Vianetz_AdvancedInvoiceLayout via the app/code/etc/modules xml file for the module and now the pdf's print again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is due to a bug in the PayOne Module version 3.1.8

The friendly technical support at PayOne sent me a pre-release of the bugfixed version and this solved the issue.

The actual release of the bugfix should not take too long for Magento Connect, but if you are in a hurry I would recommend ringing PayOne Merchant Services and ask to be transferred to the Technical Support.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it seams that one of the custom extensions does not behave as it should or it interferes with the invoice printing.

The custom extensions mentioned in the error message are `Payone_Core` and `Vianetz_AdvancedInvoiceLayout`.

it looks like the culprit is `Vianetz_AdvancedInvoiceLayout`.
Disabling the extension seams to fix the issue.
Being a paid extension I suggest contacting the developer for support.

Comment: I have sent a support request to Vianetz as I can't find the error myself. Thanks.

Comment: Seems the issue is a PayOne Module error. When trying to add an order in the backend, I receive the same error when I try to add an item to the order. I have sent a request to the PayOne Developers.

Comment: I have edited my first post above. So far there has been no response from PayOne.

Comment: You can try to debug step by step starting from what the exception suggests. Maybe this helps. http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/428/146

Comment: Thanks Marius, I'll try and work my way through that. Is there any specific part I should start with? Surely from the error log, one would try and find out what the PayOne module is trying to get from the database when it's requesting the config for the payment method and why it is failing, or what is returned instead.

Answer (score 0):

A found a solution!
you have to set the "Use Global Settings" param (in Configuration -> Payment-Methods -> [Payment Method])to No and then configure payment method